# Save/restore NSWindow position

Tags: cocoa, osx-mountain-lion

I have a document based Mac app and I'm trying to save/restore the window position for each of my document windows.

I'm calling setWindowFrameAutosaveName on the NSWindowController when the document loads (setting it to the file name) and all is well.

Problem I have is how to deal with the scenario where a new document is created and the user closes the window and then chooses where to save the new document - I can't figure out where to call setWindowFrameAutosaveName such that it's after the document has a path but before the window controller has persisted the position.

Any pointers would be most welcome!

Thanks